# Mute sound from wkwebview when device ringer is switched off

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, swift2, wkwebview

I am using wkWebView to display web content and videos

When the user switch the device ringer off i want the webView sound to switch off to

I tried this:

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient)
        try audioSession.setActive(true)

    } catch _ {
        print("error setting catagory!")
    }
```

But it dont work - the ringer is off but music is still on

Comment: Did you found a solution?